# SQL Script to know join relationship between FACT & Dimension Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, dimension

I have working in data warehouse project that uses MS-BI as its technology stack. The database contains Dimensions and fact tables but I would like to know the joining column between dimension and fact table. Is there any sql script that could find the joining column between dimension and the fact table?

Thanks

Comment: Not a script solution but in SSMS you can create a `New Database Diagram` and add all tables to find the joining columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following query in order to get all foreign key between each fact table and dimension table in your data warehouse.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys
SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_key_columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Data Warehouse database is a database like none data warehouse database and you can get list of relations by using system tables such as `sys.foreign_keys` and also can get columns of each relation by using `sys.foreign_keyColumns`.